# Оптимизация Content под разные разрешения Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется список кнопок, которые расположены одна под другой и не вмещающихся в видимую область на девайсах. При помощи `Scroll Rect` реализовано "проматывание" данной области, но при разных разрешениях `Content` начинает плыть и некоторые данные пропадают из видимой области.

На приведенных ниже изображениях, думаю, будет понятнее ситуация:

При соотношении 9:16

[image: При соотношении 9:16]

При "Free Aspect" и мелких разрешениях

[image: При "Free Aspect" и мелких разрешениях]

При разрешении 1440x2960 и соотношении 18.5:9

[image: При разрешении 1440x2960 и соотношении 18.5:9]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, есть несколько известных мне решений.

Первое - [Content Size Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html). Это компонент, который изменяет размеры объекта, на котором висит исходя из размера чайлдов. Вешать его нужно на ваш Content. Для его работы необходима любой LayoutGroup на том же объекте. В полях этого компонента выбирается исходя из какой логики будут выбираться высота и ширина объекта.

Второе - [CanvasScaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html). Этот компонент работает на другом уровне - он изменяет скейл всех вложенных объектов исходя из выбранной логики. Вешается он автоматически на Canvas верхнего уровня. Там можно выбрать, например, режим  `Scale With Screen Size` в этом случае весь UI вы будете настраивать для конкретного разрешения, а уже скейлер будет менять скейл в зависимости от реального разрешения.